# Question on quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

I know that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ stands for the quotient group of integers mod $n$. To be a little more specific, we define the relation:
$$a \equiv b \hspace{0.1cm} (\mbox{mod $n$}) \iff n\mid (a-b)$$
and this is an equivalence relation. Thus, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is defined to be the set of all equivalence classes of this relation. We can prove that:
$$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} = \{[0],...,[n-1]\}$$ 
This being said, I would like to understand the meaning of $\mathbb{Z}^{d}/n\mathbb{Z}^{d}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{d}/n\mathbb{Z}^{d}$. I'm having trouble understanding these objects because I don't know how to define 'divisibility' in $\mathbb{Z}^{d}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. Do we need to demand componentwise divisibility? How to define these groups?

Comment: $\mathbb Z^d/n\mathbb Z^d$ would have elements $(c_1,c_2,\dots c_d)$, where each $c_i\in\{[0],...,[n-1]\}$; $(a_1,a_2,\dots a_d)\equiv(b_1, b_2,\dots b_d)\iff \forall i, n|a_i-b_i$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner this was my guess. So, in practice $\mathbb{Z}^{d}/n\mathbb{Z}^{d} = (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{d}$?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An element of $n\mathbb Z^d$ is $n$ times an element of $\mathbb Z^d$. So it's a list of $d$ integers, all of which are divisible by $n$. Two elements of $\mathbb Z^d$ are equivalent in $\mathbb Z^d/n\mathbb Z^d$ if and only if their difference is in $n\mathbb Z^d$. So $(p_0,\dots,p_{d-1})=(q_0,\dots,q_{d-1})$ if and only if $n|(p_i-q_i)$ for all $i<d$.

Comment: Does the same hold for $\mathbb{R}^{d}/n\mathbb{Z}^{d}$?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same.

Comment: @MathMath In $\mathbb R^d/n\mathbb Z^d$ we have $(x_0,\dots,x_{d-1})=(y_0,\dots,y_{d-1})$ if and only if $x_i-y_i$ is an integer for each $i<d$, and that integer divides by $n$.

Comment: I think I got it! Does $\mathbb{R}^{d}/n\mathbb{Z}^{d}$ have an 'explicit form' as in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} = \{[0],...,[n-1]\}$?

Comment: @MathMath Sure, it's $[0,1)^d$ (where $[0,1)$ is the interval of real $x$ such that $0\leq x<1$).