# Proving that $\mathbb{Z}^{d}/n\mathbb{Z}^{d} = (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{d}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

This question is a continuation of my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3687196/question-on-quotient-groups?noredirect=1#comment7577681_3687196) on quotient groups. I know that:
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} = \{[0],...,[n-1]\} \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
and, from the asnwers I got in my post, it must follow that $\mathbb{Z}^{d}/n\mathbb{Z}^{d} = (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{d}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{d}/n\mathbb{Z}^{d} = [0,1)^{d}$. But I don't know how to prove these two equalities.

For the first one, I have a little sketch in my mind that goes like this. Define the following equivalence relation on $\mathbb{Z}^{d}$
$$a \equiv b \hspace{0.1cm} \mbox{(mod $n$)} \iff \mbox{$n|(a_{i}-b_{i})$ for each $i=1,...,d$} $$
where $a= (a_{1},...,a_{d}), b=(b_{1},...,b_{d}) \in \mathbb{Z}^{d}$. We define equivalent classes:
$$[a]_{d}:= \{b \in \mathbb{Z}^{d}: \hspace{0.1cm} a \equiv b \hspace{0.1cm} \mbox{(mod $n$)}\}$$
Then, we must have something like:
$$[a]_{d} = \{b \in \mathbb{Z}^{d}: \hspace{0.1cm} n|(a_{i}-b_{i}) \hspace{0.1cm} \forall i \in \{1,...,d\}\} = \{b\in \mathbb{Z}^{d}: \hspace{0.1cm} b_{i} \in [a_{i}]\} = [a_{1}]\times\cdots\times [a_{d}]$$
where $[a_{i}]$ is the equivalence class of $a_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.Thus, the set of all equivalence classes $[b]_{d}$ should be the set of all cartesian products $[a_{1}]\times\cdots[a_{d}]$ and, by (\ref{1}), we must have $\mathbb{Z}^{d}/n\mathbb{Z}^{d} = (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{d}$.But I don't know if my reasoning is correct or if is the best approach to the problem.

Furthermre, I have no idea on how to address the problem $\mathbb{R}^{d}/n\mathbb{Z}^{d} = [0,1)^{d}$. Can someone help me here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the map
\begin{align}
f :~~~~~~~~\mathbb{Z}^d \to &\left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^d\\
\sum_{i=1}^d \alpha_i e_i \mapsto & \left( \overline{\alpha_1},\ldots,\overline{\alpha_d}\right)
\end{align}
where $\overline{\alpha}$ is the reduction modulo $n$ of $\alpha$, and $\{e_1,\ldots,e_d\}$ stands for the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Show first that it is a group homomorphism (it is easy). Show that it is surjective (easy too). Thus, check its kernel : you can show that $\ker f = \left(n\mathbb{Z}\right)^d$. Hence, $f$ goes to the quotient $\overline{f} : \mathbb{Z}^d / \ker f \to \left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^d$ as a group homomorphism, which is surjective (as $f$ is), and injective by construction. It is then an isomorphism.

Careful : $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is not $[0,1)$ (at least, not written like that). We usually prefer to denote it $\mathbb{S}^1$. The same proof than above show that $\mathbb{R}^d / \mathbb{Z}^d \simeq \left(\mathbb{S}^1\right)^d$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Well, I am not experienced in algebra,but I think I get the idea. Just to clarify, the reduction modulo $n$ means $\bar{\alpha}$ is the equivalence class for which $\alpha$ belongs?

Comment: PS: Is my sketch too bad?

Comment: Yes it is exactly what $\overline{\alpha}$ means! The "hard" part is to show that the map $\overline{f}$ is well defined, but you get the idea. I think your sketch is good, but you don't have the algebra language which makes the proof easier.

Comment: Perfect! Your proof is very different, but is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Just one more thing: do you know if the relation on $\mathbb{Z}^{d}/n\mathbb{Z}^{d}$ has a name? Can I call it congruence modulo $n$ on $\mathbb{Z}^{d}$ in the same way we do in the case $\mathbb{Z}$ ?